# the wrong release key hash is being generated by openssl facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, openssl

I'm trying to implement facebook login to my app that I will publish on the playstore. To do this, we need to generate a release key hash. I tried to generate it by following the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) under the section titled "Setting a Release Key Hash". This is the command they tell us to execute (for Windows 7)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

ofcourse replacing `<RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS>` and `<RELEASE_KEY_PATH>`. I'm getting the 28-character hash key. But when I try to run my app, it's giving me an error

> Invalid key hash. The key hash Hhle8*********************** does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at `http://developers.facebook.com/apps/<MY_APP_ID>`

Now I know why it's an error, the key hash in the error message above isn't the same as the one generated by the command I executed (keytool -exportcert.....)

I'm new to this, and extremely confused, any help will be much appreciated. Why are the keyhashes different? I'm testing my app on a real device.

Comment: @Rockstart5645 just Add that generated keyhash to your Facebook App.

Comment: The one in the error message? Is that the correct keyhash? Will that cause any problems when I upload to the playstore?

Comment: Invalid key hash. The key hash Hhle8*********************** does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/<MY_APP_ID>  This error message says that the key hash is not register with your facebook app.So Add that key in your facebook App

Answer (score 0):

This link may be helpful as it also shows how to generate fb hadh key using code-http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-key-hashes-for-android-facebook-app

Comment: Yea, this shows how to generate the debug keyhash. But it will only work on your device. I want the release key hash, to upload my app to the playstore.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using eclipse to sign your application there's an easy way to do this.

Right click on your Project > Android Tools > Export signed application

Choose or create keystore and complete the process. At the end part where you will be ask where to store your apk. You will be given a MD5 and SHA1 hex values. Copy your SHA1 and go to [Hexadecimal -> base64 string decoder](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)

Paste it on Hex string and click convert. There will be a warning just press ok. Then you will be given a base64 keyhash that you can use.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio dude, and I signed my application and I specified a directory to store my signed apk file. It's creating one every time I run my project.